# How to do multiple-sort? e.g. sort by character length AND group alpabetically

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how can you do multi-sorting?

I have a single column: a long list of let's say 3000 names.

I want to sort by character length and group them alphabetically, like so:

**Original list:**

```
b
aaa
cccc
cc
bb
aaaaaa
......
```

**Desired list:**

```
aaa
aaaa
aaaaaaa
b
bb
bbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cc
cccc
ccccc
ccccccccccc
```

Comment: Your post example is a bad one, since a regular sort of the data you show would produce the result you want alphabetically. That is, strings of 'a' will always be placed alphabetically in order by length and then strings of 'b' in order by length, etc., just based on regular alphabetization rules (e.g., 'a' 'aardvark' 'aardwolf' 'abacus' etc.). I would encourage you to exchange your current generic post data with data that better represents your real need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to your original post.

However, theoretically, suppose you had first names (e.g., Bob, Al, Abigail, Aaron, Bill) running A2:A. Try the following formula in B2:

`=QUERY(FILTER({A2:A,LEFT(A2:A),LEN(A2:A)},A2:A<>""),"Select Col1 ORDER BY Col2, Col3, Col1")`

This should produce the following order:

Al

Aaron

Abigail

Bob

Bill

The `FILTER` function alone would create a three-column array containing the original names, the first character of each name and the length of each name, restricted to only non-null entries from A2:A.

`QUERY` then selects the just first column from the `FILTER` results (i.e., the original names), according to a prioritized order: first letter, length, then full name (the latter of which will apply normal alphabetization rules for names that start with the same letter and are the same length, e.g., **Jack Jane Jill John**).